# Rsync --delete option isn't deleting hidden dotfiles in target

Tags: bash, shell, filesystems, rsync

These are the steps I took:

Create some test files:

```
/tmp $ mkdir src tgt
/tmp $ cd src/
/tmp/src $ touch .test{1,2,3}
/tmp/src $ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   5 user  wheel  170 18 Aug 15:02 .
drwxrwxrwt  11 root       wheel  374 18 Aug 15:02 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 user  wheel    0 18 Aug 15:02 .test1
-rw-r--r--   1 user  wheel    0 18 Aug 15:02 .test2
-rw-r--r--   1 user  wheel    0 18 Aug 15:02 .test3
```

Sync the src and tgt directories:

```
/tmp/src $ cd ..
/tmp $ rsync -avh --delete --progress src/.??* tgt
building file list ...
3 files to consider
.test1
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=2/3)
.test2
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=1/3)
.test3
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3, to-check=0/3)

sent 209 bytes  received 86 bytes  590.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
/tmp $ ls -la tgt/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   5 user  wheel  170 18 Aug 15:03 .
drwxrwxrwt  11 root       wheel  374 18 Aug 15:02 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 user  wheel    0 18 Aug 15:02 .test1
-rw-r--r--   1 user  wheel    0 18 Aug 15:02 .test2
-rw-r--r--   1 user  wheel    0 18 Aug 15:02 .test3
```

Delete a file in the src and sync again:

```
/tmp $ rm -rf src/.test1
/tmp $ ls -la src/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   4 user  wheel  136 18 Aug 15:03 .
drwxrwxrwt  11 root       wheel  374 18 Aug 15:02 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 user  wheel    0 18 Aug 15:02 .test2
-rw-r--r--   1 user  wheel    0 18 Aug 15:02 .test3
/tmp $ rsync -avh --delete --progress src/.??* tgt
building file list ...
2 files to consider

sent 75 bytes  received 20 bytes  190.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
/tmp $ ls -la tgt/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   5 user  wheel  170 18 Aug 15:03 .
drwxrwxrwt  11 root       wheel  374 18 Aug 15:02 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 user  wheel    0 18 Aug 15:02 .test1
-rw-r--r--   1 user  wheel    0 18 Aug 15:02 .test2
-rw-r--r--   1 user  wheel    0 18 Aug 15:02 .test3
```

The .test1 file didn't get deleted in the tgt directory.

Why doesn't the --delete option work in this case?

How do I get the rsync command to delete hidden files in the target?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with hidden files. After `rm` you never told `rsync` to care about `src/.test1` at all. From `man 1 rsync` [emphasis mine]:

> `--delete`
>   This tells `rsync` to delete extraneous files from the receiving side (ones that aren’t on the sending side), but **only for the directories that are being synchronized. You must have asked `rsync` to send the whole directory (e.g. `dir` or `dir/`) without using a wildcard for the directory’s contents (e.g. `dir/*`)** since the wildcard is expanded by the shell and `rsync` thus gets a  request to transfer individual files, not the files’ parent directory. […]

Sync directories, not individual files:

```
rsync -avh --delete --progress src/ tgt
```

Comment: This does the delete of hidden dotfiles in tgt which is great, however I need the command to only sync the hidden dotfiles, your command syncs all the files in src. Do you have some other way to only sync the dotfiles?

Comment: This command appears to work: rsync -avh --delete --progress --include '\.*' --exclude '*' src/ tgt

Comment: @vy218 I believe I answered the two explicit questions from the question body. You wrote "Sync the src and tgt directories" as if this was what you intended to do. And your example doesn't include other files. There was no way to tell there are files you don't want to sync. Now you're revealing a hidden requirement. The requirement should be in the question from the very beginning. The question shouldn't be substantially changed after someone answers. One solution is to accept my answer (delete yours) and ask a separate self-answered question which does include your requirement.

Comment: @vy218 Another solution is to improve the current question (add the requirement in a clear way) and accept your own answer. Then I will delete my answer and let it go. But this is only my courtesy; in general you shouln't invalidate existing answers by changing the question substantially.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to sync dirs (as mentioned by @Kamil Maciorowski), but also us the include and exclude filters so only the dot files are synced in the first place:

rsync -avh --delete --progress --include '.*' --exclude '*' src/ tgt

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding `--ignore-errors` solved the problem.

More details:
Using cygwin to copy from a linux server to a windows USB drive.

Source is `server:/src` and destination is `/cygdrive/e`.

There was a hidden file left over from a previous rsync run. The file name was something like `.data.qpSS6L`

Running the following command did **not** delete the file:

```
rsync -rvvth --update server:/src /cygdrive/e --delete
```

The following adds --ignore-errors and deleted the hidden file correctly:

```
rsync -rvvth --update server:/src /cygdrive/e --delete --ignore-errors
```